# Kafka Python Client - How to handle possible connection/timeout errors?

Tags: python-3.x, kafka-producer-api, kafka-python

I am writing a Python application which connects to a Kafka queue and sends a message to the queue. I have the following working code:

```
def send_msg(self, topic, msg):
    self.producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=['XX.XXX.XX.XXX:XXXX'])
    future = self.producer.send(topic, msg)
    self.producer.flush()
```

I want to add the standard try-catch expressions in this code so that I can catch any kind of exceptions that I might face. What are the various exceptions like connection, timeout, NoBrokersAvailable and how should I properly handle them?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Set `advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://<broker_ip>:9092` in `server.properties`. Restart your kafka-server and consumer and try again.

Please find my answer given in another thread, same problem as yours.
[NoBrokersAvailable: NoBrokersAvailable-Kafka Error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46441154/786676)